# Request for new site for the Persian/Farsi language

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

I would like to see a Persian/Farsi language site included within the Stack Exchange world. How likely is this? Is it already being considered?

Answer (score 3):

There already appears to be a [Persian and other Iranian languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77079/persian-and-other-iranian-languages) proposal on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), our site for proposing new sites.

You can follow and commit to the proposal - if it gains enough support, it will get the chance to become a site on the network.

Comment: Thanks; I assumed Area51 was about aliens.

Comment: The proposal for Persian seems to have been deleted: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40653/stack-overflow-in-persian

Comment: I added a new one: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80551/persian-farsi-language?referrer=ZiZ-1wX9HaR8VHdCMlrQzg2